# When Should a Tag Be Defined?

Tags: discussion, tags

I realize there is no definite answer here, but I'm curious as to a consensus...
Perusing the tags not defined yet, there are an awful lot that have a score of 2. Some of these I see being used more in the future, and am inclined to fill out. That said, I realize that's flawed because it is merely opinion.
tldr:
Is it worth it to add definitions to tags with little to no activity?
Another way to say that is there any value to be had by defining them?
More value to wait it out and see which actually gain traction?

Comment: I used to add description to anything regardless the frequency of use. Even if there is only one who has chose it, then there is a possibility to be used in the future for someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is value in adding description for existing tags, and also for retagging where needed.

Of course we will probably get a better understanding as more question arrive, but we should start improving the tags now, as it already makes the site more useful, and helps avoid duplicate questions.